# Wordpress - Javascript enqueue

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a wordpress website and I know that to run scripts on a wordpress page, you need to enqueue the script in the functions.php file. I am not sure how to do this proccess?

my Javascript is called boosting.js
Can someone give me an example code of how to do this?
Thank you very much! (I am a bit new to all this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this to functions.php.

`script-name` - is the name you want to give the script

`get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/boosting.js'` - is path to where the script is located. If you're using a child theme then change this to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/boosting.js'`

`array()` - this is for dependencies. If your script needs jQuery to work than use `array('jquery')`

`1.0.0` - version of the script. Useful for caching

`true` - means that the script will be loaded in the footer, use `false` if you needed in the header

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles.
*/
function wp_theme_enque_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/boosting.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_theme_enque_scripts' );
```

You can read more here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: Hi, I enqued the required scripts in the functions.php like this:

 `function wp_theme_enque_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'boosting', get_template_directory_uri() . '/csgoboost/js/boosting.js', array('header'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/csgoboost/js/jquery.js', array('header'), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/csgoboost/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('header'), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_theme_enque_scripts' );`

Is it correct?

Comment: Not really, no. JQuery is enqueued by WordPress so you don't need to to.
Change your code to this:

`function wp_theme_enque_scripts() { 
wp_enqueue_script( 'boosting', get_template_directory_uri() . '/csgoboost/js/boosting.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true ); 

wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/csgoboost/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.3.6', true ); } 

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_theme_enque_scripts' ); `

Comment: Since you're adding Bootstrap then you probably need to also add the css. In the same function also add

`wp_register_style('bootstrap.css', get_template_directory_uri() . 'csgoboost/css/bootstrap.css', array(), '3.3.6', 'all' );
 wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap.css');`

Comment: To check if it's working (it may not if the path used is not the right one), refresh your site, and view the Source code (CTRL + U) and look for the bootstrap css, js and your boosting.js and click on them. If they open then path used is good.

Comment: Okay so I added the correct function with the CSS but when I check the Source Code, there is no boostrap css, js and no boosting.js. What could be causing this? The pathing is correct if the `get_template_directory_uri()` is right... I am very confused

Comment: I'd be ready to pay you a little bit if you can personally help me get this problem fixed. I've been trying to fix this since a week and I'm very desperate at this point. I can pay you like 5$ if you can help me get this problem fixed. Thank you very much :)